# Using a Galaxy s7 camera with the raspberry pi

Tags: camera

It is possible to use a Sony IMX 260 sensor with the rasberry pi?

Answer (score 2):

Only in the sense that you can use a Pi to send 'take a picture' signals to a Galaxy S7 phone. You can't connect the sensor directly to the Pi - you're missing all of the relevant drivers and the correct hardware interface.